# Getting code signing identity on runtime?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to get code signing identity information at runtime ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can get a lot of code signing information at run-time from the file *embedded.mobileprovision*:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"embedded.mobileprovision" ofType:nil]
```

There's a discussion about it in [How to determine at run-time if app is for development, app store or ad hoc distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426467/how-to-determine-at-run-time-if-app-is-for-development-app-store-or-ad-hoc-distr)

It's not that easy to read the file because it is a DER-encoded ASN.1 file.

Comment: Codo, thank your for answer.
Sounds like good, I will try your advice asap.

Comment: Codo,
As far as I see, It won't be easy. Could you share me if you find something about this.

Comment: From what Ive seen, embedded.mobileprovision isnt included in IPAs from the AppStore. Or maybe it was and this has changed in iOS 4 or 5.

Comment: Yes, the file is missing in apps from the AppStore. It has always been like this.

Answer (score 0):

via [.mobileprovision Files Structure and Reading](http://idevblog.info/mobileprovision-files-structure-and-reading/) — the application binary should still be signed, even with the embedded.mobileprovision stripped in the apps tore.